# Docker-compose container using host DNS server

Tags: networking, docker, dns, docker-compose

I'm running several containers on my "Ubuntu 16.10 Server" in a "custom" bridge network with compose 2.9 (in a yml version 2.1). Most of my containers are internally using the same ports, so there is no way for me to use the "host" network driver.
My containers are all links together, using the dedicated `links` attribute.

But, I also need to access services exposed outside of my containers. These services have dedicated URL with names registered in my company's DNS server.
While I have no problem to use public DNS and reach any public service from within my containers, I just can't reach my private DNS.

Do you know a working solution to use private DNS from a container? Or even better, use host's network DNS configuration?

PS: Of course, I can link to my company's services using the `extra_hosts` attribute in my services in my docker-compose.yml file. But... that's definitively not the goal of having a DNS. I don't want to register all my services in my YML file, and I don't want to update it each time services' IP are updated in my company.

**Context :**

- Host: Ubuntu 16.10 server
- Docker Engine: 1.12.6
- Docker Compose: 1.9.0
- docker-compose.yml: 2.1
- Network: Own bridge.

**docker-compose.yml file (extract):**

```
version: '2.1'
  services:
    nexus:
    image: sonatype/nexus3:$NEXUS_VERSION
    container_name: nexus
    restart: always
    hostname: nexus.$URL
    ports:
      - "$NEXUS_81:8081"
      - "$NEXUS_443:8443"
    extra_hosts:
      - "repos.private.network:192.168.200.200"
    dns:
      - 192.168.3.7
      - 192.168.111.1
      - 192.168.10.5
      - 192.168.10.15
    volumes_from:
      - nexus-data
    networks:
      - pic

  networks:
    pic:
      driver: bridge
      ipam:
        driver: default
        config:
          - subnet: 172.18.0.0/16
            gateway: 172.18.0.1
```

I tried with and without the `ipam` configuration for the `pic` network, without any luck.

**Tests & Results:**
`docker exec -ti nexus curl repos.private.network`
returns properly the HTML page served by this service

`docker exec -ti nexus curl another-service.private.network`
Returns `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: another-service.private.network; Name or service not known`
While `curl another-service.private.network` from the host returns the appropriate HTML page.

And "of course" `another-service.private.network` is known in my 4 DNS servers (192.168.3.7, 192.168.111.1, 192.168.10.5, 192.168.10.15).

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You don't specify which environment you're running docker-compose in e.g Mac, Windows or Unix, so it will depend a little bit on what changes are needed. You also don't specify if you're using the default bridge network in docker on a user created bridge network.

In either case, by default, Docker should try and map DNS resolution from the Docker Host into your containers. So if your Docker Host can resolve the private DNS addresses, then in theory your containers should be able to as well.

I'd recommend reading this official Docker DNS documentation as it is pretty reasonable. [Here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/) for the default Docker bridge network, [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/) for user created bridge networks.

A slight gotcha is if you're running using Docker for Mac, Docker Machine or Docker for Windows you need to remember that your Docker Host is actually the VM running on your machine and not the physical box itself, so you need to ensure that the VM has the correct DNS resolution options set. You will need to restart your containers for changes to DNS resolution to be picked up by them.

You can of course override all the default settings using `docker-compose`. It has full options for explicitly setting DNS servers, DNS search options etc. As an example:

```
version: 2
services:
 application:
  dns:
   - 8.8.8.8
   - 4.4.4.4
   - 192.168.9.45
```

You'll find the documentation for those features [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/dns).

Comment: Hi @Rob, Thanks for your answer. I'm editing my original post to add details about my conf (running on Ubuntu 16.10 server with a custom bridge).

Comment: Updated link with the various dns options: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/

Comment: You might also need to add `network_mode` to the YAML. E.g.: `network_mode: "bridge"`

Comment: just out of curiosity do you list the google dns server first for a reason? I assume this searches in order meaning checks google first (8.8.8.8) then whatever 4.4.4.4 is then lastly the custom dns server? So if we want to override something like stackoverflow.com and point at a different IP address we would have to list the custom domain server first I think? follow up question. Assuming our host already uses 8.8.8.8 do we need to list it or do we just need to list the custom internal dns server? in other words is the compose.yml additive or it replaces the list?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#dns