# A Windows container deployed to Service Fabric with isolation cannot resolve DNS

Tags: azure, docker-compose, azure-service-fabric

I deploy a container to a Service Fabric cluster (both Windows) in isolation with a `docker-compose.yml` like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  webhost:
    image: xxxxxcr.azurecr.io/container.image:latest
    isolation: hyperv
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
    ports:
      - 80/http
    environment:
...
```

But this container is not able to resolve DNS. When executing a `nslookup` inside the container it shows:

```
C:\>nslookup xxxxxdatabase.documents.azure.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  172.31.240.1

*** UnKnown can't find xxxxxdatabase.documents.azure.com: Server failed
```

Deploying exactly the same image without `isolation: hyperv` does not cause into this problem.

I tried - without success - to add `dns` entries to the compose file as [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41717180/docker-compose-container-using-host-dns-server). As it seems the `dns` may not be supported for [Service Fabric compose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-docker-compose#supported-compose-directives).

More details:

- nodes have this VM image: `WindowsServerSemiAnnual / Datacenter-Core-1803-with-Containers-smalldisk / 1803.0.20190115`
- base image is: `microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-1803`

What do I need to do to get DNS resolution in this isolated container?