# docker-compose: calls to external api are very slow

Tags: docker, docker-compose

For a while, I had all my applications in Docker and I would start them using `docker run ...` Some of these services rely on 3rd party API (e.g. Twitter) but when launching them from docker-compose (same server) the request is 10x slower (~300ms vs ~4s).

Some of these 3rd party API are actually on the same service and when I don't include them in the docker-compose and call them via the docker-compose alias but through a DNS I observe the same behavior.

What am I doing wrong?

Docker runs on an Ubuntu server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of [Docker-compose container using host DNS server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41717180/docker-compose-container-using-host-dns-server) and the provided link: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

I added

```
dns:
  - 8.8.8.8
```

which solves the issue