# Docker for Windows - How to reach external host on the same LAN

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Docker for Windows newbie here.

I need one of the containers to reach a web server located in one of the machines of the same LAN (**192.168.1.134**) where the host machine resides (**192.168.1.100**), but I don't understand how to do it.

Containers are started via docker-compose, with a configuration like this :

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  myapp:
    image: 'docker.io/bitnami/codeigniter:latest'
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
  mariadb:
    volumes:
      - ./docker_data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    image: 'docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:10.3-debian-10'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxx
      MARIADB_DATABASE: xxx
      MARIADB_USER: xxx
     MARIADB_PASSWORD: xxx
  composer_installation:
    container_name: composer_installation
    image: composer
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    command: composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Containers can ping each other and I have outbound/inbound internet connectivity inside the containers,
but I can't reach IPs in my LAN

I tried modifying docker-compose by adding

```
--extra_hosts:
  - "myotherhost:192.68.1.134"
```

to "**myapp**" container - I can see host added to **/etc/hosts** file,
but I have no outbound connectivity.

I also tried to add **network_mode: bridge** , to every container configuration , but this way I lose communication between containers.

Comment: Pls check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41717180/docker-compose-container-using-host-dns-server

Comment: Yes - I checked it before starting this one, but it is still not clear how to configure the network for my easy use case..

Answer (score -2):

Just use `network_mode` as `host`

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  myapp:
    image: 'docker.io/bitnami/codeigniter:latest'
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
    network_mode: "host"
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
  mariadb:
    volumes:
      - ./docker_data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    network_mode: "host"
    image: 'docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:10.3-debian-10'
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxx
      MARIADB_DATABASE: xxx
      MARIADB_USER: xxx
     MARIADB_PASSWORD: xxx
  composer_installation:
    container_name: composer_installation
    image: composer
    network_mode: "host"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    command: composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Here I assumed all three containers need to connect to same LAN, if its for specific services, add  `network_mode: "host"` to those services only.

Comment: Thanks - Just tried it - I am now getting the error ""host" network_mode is incompatible with port_bindings" , if I remove the "ports" part I cannot connect to my container from localhost:8000 that , of course, is a requirement for development.

Comment: @user3256843 it was my mistake, with `network_mode: "host"` container exposed port is automatically exposed. No need to expose in `docker-compose` file. Please check now

Comment: From DOC : " The host networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows, or Docker EE for Windows Server " - So looks like I am screwed ?

Comment: @user3256843 sorry, i forgot about Windows part, but there should be a way to do.